# How can directories have only 1 hard link?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, symbolic-link, hardlink

When doing `ls -al`, the second column (just after the permissions) is the number of hard links. For files, I find this clear. My problem is with directories.

I read that it is not possible to create hard links to directories with the exception of `.` and `..` , and I also find this logical. Therefore, the number of hard links of a directory is related to the number of subdirectories that has because each `..` in each subdirectory is a link pointing to it.

If I understood this correctly, then I would expect that all directories should have at least hard link number 2 (the directory itself and `.`). However, in a VM from a CTF game I've seen multiple directories with hard link counters equal to 1.

How is this possible? Also, if I check the inode of the directory and `.` with `ls -ali` I can see that they both have the same inode, but both counters are 1.

I add a screenshot with a particular example. If I understood correctly, this directory should have hard link counter 3 and not 1 as it is shown.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/510880/why-does-directory-contain-2-hard-links

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/210741/why-are-hard-links-not-allowed-for-directories

Comment: Those links explain what I already know. But I cannot find any question or answer regarding the case of just hard link number = 1.

Comment: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg98964.html (Is `.ssh` a mountpoint of a non-btrfs filesystem?)

Comment: It's normal in few filesystem types. [Relying on the number of hard links is thus a mistake](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497195/108618).

Comment: Those links were useful. I suspect this is running on a Docker container using `overlayfs` (based on running `stat -f -c %T .`). But what I find weird is that there are so many exceptions. I would expect that either all directories show 1 (if using btrfs, for example) or >=2 otherwise. But I find exceptions all around.